# Can't go back to previous file

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a menu for myself using tkinter and I ran into a problem:

Menu file:

```
        def Folder():
        root.destroy()
        import Folder

    self.FolderButton = Button(text='Folders', bg='purple', command=Folder)
    self.FolderButton.config(height=5, width=10)
    self.FolderButton.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

what happens is I use this code so when I click the button I got to a new python file which has my folders. My problem is, how do I go back from my folder file too my menu file.

Folder file:

```
    def back():
        root.destroy()
        import menu
    self.BackButton = Button(text='Back', bg='black', fg='white', command=back)
    self.BackButton.config(height=1, width=22)
    self.BackButton.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
```

When ever I go back it just closes. Please help

EDIT: I now understand I shouldn't use import for this type of thing but please can someone recommend another way to do this.

EDIT: `TopLevel` Works but it doesn't open a new python file. So now I need it to open a new python file as well.

Comment: `import` statements are not meant to control the execution flow of a program! That being said, module level code is only executed once - upon the first import - in the current runtime (unless explicitly reloaded)

Comment: How to declare a button without "root". And your app will be finished if don't use a additional tracker thread !